# Using VMware ovftool to check existence of virtual machine (VM)?

Tags: virtual-machines, command-line-interface, vmware-vsphere, ovf

What is the canonical way to use VMware's `ovftool` to query to see if a VM exists or not?

If I run this command:

```
ovftool vi://username@password@myvsphere/mydatacenter/vm/myvm
```

I might get this response:

```
Error: Got fault from server: The attempted operation cannot be
performed in the current state (Powered on).
Error: Fault cause: vim.fault.InvalidState
```

I know I can do the following and then look for *"Locator does not refer to an object"* but is there a different command or *(set of)* option(s) I can run that will return a simple `true` or `false` or something else concise that does not indicate an error?

```
ovftool vi://username@password@myvsphere/mydatacenter/vm/avmthatisnothere
```

Just FYI the above returns this:

```
Error: Locator does not refer to an object:
vi://username@password@myvsphere/mydatacenter/vm/avmthatisnothere
```

Comment: A follow up: I ended up using `govc`. It requires vCenter's API, but fortunately for my use-case we were using vCenter: 

https://github.com/mikeschinkel/govmomi/blob/master/govc/USAGE.md

Answer (score 1):

You cannot request operations on the vm while its running, but your output also suggests, that the VM you query actually exists. So if you get an output similar to:

```
Error: Got fault from server: The attempted operation cannot be performed in the current state (Powered on).
Error: Fault cause: vim.fault.InvalidState
```

The VM actually exists and is in ON state.

If you get something like

```
Error: Locator does not refer to an object: vi://...
```

The object / the VM does not exist.

Im unable to test the situation when the VM exists, but is turned off, but I believe you will get the information about the datasotore on which the VM is hosted etc.

Unfortunately there is no simple true/false command here. You can wrap this in a script, but you will have to parse the output of the command (stdout and stderr) to do the decision making.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong tool. You cannot serve beer with a fork.

> VMware OVF Tool is a command-line utility that allows you to import and export OVF packages to and from many VMware products.

To check whether a VM with the name `myVM` exists you should try PowerCLI:

```
Get-VM -Name myVM
```

https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/commands/get-vm/#Default

Comment: Seems strange that a tool that can power-on and power-off a VM is not the right tool to determine if a VMs actually exist to power on or off.  That said, it seems like [a huge amount of effort](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/06/01/how-to-install-and-use-powershell-and-powercli-on-linux.aspx) to use the _"right"_ tool just to test for existence when by side-effect I can use `ovftool` in a much lighter weight manner to check the same thing.